# Applescript keystrokes in a Input Source independent way

Tags: applescript, clipboard

I want to write an Applescript that does multiple copy-and-paste between other keystrokes. So this is a sample of what I've done:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set the clipboard to "^"
    keystroke "v" using command down
    keystroke "a"
    set the clipboard to "~"
    keystroke "v" using command down
    keystroke "a"
end tell
```

I'm expecting to get `^a~a` typed when running the above script with `osascript`, but I'm getting `~a~a` instead. Looks like the keystrokes are executed after all the "set the clipboard" instructions.

How can I have a sequence of copy-and-paste instructions in the same script?

**EDIT:** the main reason I'm doing this is to be able to auto-type characters in a way that works independently of the Input Source enabled. So I would get the expected sequence of characters with U.S. or with some other Input Source that otherwise would result in `âã` if we just had the four symbols above typed in sequence. Adding spaces after the accent characters would work for this kind of Input Source, but would give me `^ a~ a` with U.S., so that is not the general solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a delay solves the issue. In script bellow, it types in TextEdit :

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
tell application "System Events"
set the clipboard to "^"
keystroke "v" using command down
keystroke "a"
delay 0.05
set the clipboard to "~"
keystroke "v" using command down
keystroke "a"
end tell
```

I assume that you have good reasons, not explained here, to not just do :

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "^ a~ a"
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I updated my answer with the reason I'm doing it this way. Do you see a better solution for this?

Comment: Clear. If it should work with any keyboards, then I understand. in that case, I have no other solution.